# How to update Kepler.gl MapBox component style

Tags: kepler.gl

I'm trying to figure out how to customize the kepler.gl's mapbox style. I want to make the mapbox component fill the screen width and height.

I've already tried updating it using the dispatcher with no success:

```
this.props.dispatch(loadCustomMapStyle({inputStyle: {url: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-guidance-day-v4', id: 'some-id', style: {width: '100%', height: '100%'}}}));

this.props.dispatch(addCustomMapStyle());
```

I also tried using the styled-components ThemeProvider:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={{width: '100%', height:'100%'}}>
            <KeplerGl
                id="foo"
                mapboxApiAccessToken={'API_KEY'}
                store={store}
              />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KeplerGl component takes in `width` and `height` props (documentation [here](https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl#width-number-optional)). To change these with the dimensions of a div, you can use [AutoSizer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/usingAutoSizer.md). For example, for the KeplerGl component to fill the screen you could wrap it in a div that is fullscreen as follows:

```
import AutoSizer from 'react-virtualized/dist/commonjs/AutoSizer';

...

<div style={{position: "absolute", width: "100%", height: "100%"}}> 
    <AutoSizer>
        {({height, width}) => (
            <KeplerGl
                mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
                id="map"
                width={width}
                height={height}
            />  
        )}  
    </AutoSizer>
</div>
```